# c++ "Case label value exceed maximum value for type"

Tags: c++

So I have this assignment for class and I need to use switch statements and the case values must be 2,4,6,8,and 10. The problem is when I use 10 as a case value and then do g++ it says the case label value exceeds the maximum for type. Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Here's my code. It works perfectly if I use any number lower than 10.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char number;
cout << "Enter a number. ";
cin >> number;
switch(number)
{
case '2':
cout << "shoe\n";break;
case '4':
cout <<"door\n";break;
case '6':
cout <<"sticks\n";break;
case '8':
cout <<"straight\n";break;
case '10':
cout <<"big fat hen\n";break;
default:
cout << "Not much into kids' rhymes, ar you?\n" << endl;
}   
}
```

Comment: You're confusing characters with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'10'` is not a character, it is two characters, which is not allowed.  If you want to store numbers, you should not be using the `'` characters:

```
case 8:
   cout <<"straight\n";break;
case 10:
   ...
```

Instead, you should probably read input as type `int`.

Comment: '10' is allowed!  the reason why he's getting the error is because his switch is on a char, and '10' is outside of the range of char.

Comment: C++ can switch on strings?

Comment: '10' is not a string.  "10" is a string.

Comment: Exactly.  So '10' is not a `char` or a `string`... so I'd say what he is doing is not allowed.  Is there some unicode thing that I'm missing?  I'm by no means an expert in C++.

Comment: the reason why he's getting the error is because he's switching on char and '10' is not a char.  that's why the message says "value exceed maximum value for type” (i.e. '10' is outside of the range of char).  now he should remove the quotes anyway because otherwise it is a bug, but your diagnosis is not entirely correct.  '10' is allowed.  for example:  int x; switch(x){ case '10': printf("hi\r\n"); break; } is legit.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.  That's definitely not defined behavior in C.

Comment: There's no should use `int` about it, if the `char` literals in the switch are changed to integers, it will then switch on the ascii value of the char read from the stream. The change from `char` to `int` is a must.

Comment: also see the answer above.  removing the quotes requires changing the type to int as well because >> reads literal char.  otherwise, you can't go above 9.

Comment: It's called a multicharacter literal FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the quotes around the numbers.

Comment: Even if he does that, he'll still be switching on a character's ascii value instead of a number read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is typically not treated as a number, and certainly not when it comes to reading from a stream. Also, when switching on numbers, don't use character literals:

See commented changes (not tested):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number; // char isn't a number in this use case, use int
cout << "Enter a number. ";
cin >> number;
switch(number)
{
case 2: // not character literals
cout << "shoe\n";break;
case 4:
cout <<"door\n";break;
case 6:
cout <<"sticks\n";break;
case 8:
cout <<"straight\n";break;
case 10: // '10' is an illegal character literal, as its 2 characters
cout <<"big fat hen\n";break;
default:
cout << "Not much into kids' rhymes, ar you?\n" << endl;
}   
}
```